# Adding labels to a matrix

Tags: matrices

I don't know how to add labels "ABCDE" and "12345678910". And I want to set it as a matrix and not as a table. How can I achieve that?

> DESIRED OUTPUT:
>   [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}

        & 5 & 4 & 4 & - & \textbf{5} \\
        & - & 3 & 5 &\textbf{ 3} & 4 \\
        & 5 & 2 & - & \textbf{2} & 3 \\
        & - & \textbf{2} & 3 & 1 & 2     \\
        & 4 & - & \textbf{5} & 4 & 5     \\
        &  \textbf{5}&3  & - & 3 & 5 \\
        &3  & \textbf{2} & 3 & 2 & - \\
        &5  & \textbf{3} & 4 & - & 5 \\
        & \textbf{4} & 2 & 5 & 4 &-  \\
        &\textbf{5}  & - & 5 & 3 & 4 \\
        &  &  &  &  & 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\bordermatrix` should do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a hammersledge like `tikz` for that: `blkarray`  does it easily:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathbf{R }= \begin{blockarray}{r*{5}{ >{\color{LightSalmon}}c}}
& A & B & C & D & E \\
\begin{block}{ >{\scriptstyle}r!{\,}(ccccc)}
1 & 5 & 4 & 4 & - & \mathbf{5} \\
2 & - & 3 & 5 &\mathbf{ 3} & 4 \\
3 & 5 & 2 & - & \mathbf{2} & 3 \\
4 & - & \mathbf{2} & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
5 & 4 & - & \mathbf{5} & 4 & 5 \\
6 & \mathbf{5}&3 & - & 3 & 5 \\
7 & 3 & \mathbf{2} & 3 & 2 & - \\
8 & 5 & \mathbf{3} & 4 & - & 5 \\
9 & \mathbf{4} & 2 & 5 & 4 &-  \\
10 & \mathbf{5} & - & 5 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your solution is nice! but TikZ is not hammersledge IMO

Comment: With a documentation of 1302 pages?

Comment: 1302-page TikZ manual is simply the best guide for a package. I got TikZ, so I draw almost everything, I can ignore many other package, I save my memory.

Answer (score 4):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbp]
$\mathbf{R} = 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
 [first-col,
  first-row,
  code-for-first-col = \color{blue},
  code-for-first-row = \color{blue}]
& A & B & C & D & E     \\
1 &  5 & 4 & 4 & - & \mathbf{5} \\
2 &  - & 3 & 5 &\mathbf{ 3} & 4 \\
3 &  5 & 2 & - & \mathbf{2} & 3 \\
4 &  - & \mathbf{2} & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
5 &  4 & - & \mathbf{5} & 4 & 5 \\
6 & \mathbf{5}&3  & - & 3 & 5 \\
7 & 3  & \mathbf{2} & 3 & 2 & - \\
8 & 5  & \mathbf{3} & 4 & - & 5 \\
9 &  \mathbf{4} & 2 & 5 & 4 &-   \\
10 & \mathbf{5}  & - & 5 & 3 & 4 
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]